# How to display buttons on top of a bootstrap div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

my query is like rendering the buttons and hiding in each div of a form-group in boostrap.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Label 01:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txt_codigo" class="form-control" maxlength="40" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="button-wrapper">
            <label class="col-sm-3 control-label no-padding-right">Label 02:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <input type="text" id="txt_codigo" class="form-control" maxlength="40" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

I show you a screenshots I want to achieve:

[Image of how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHkbX.png)

What I want is to show the buttons on the upper right side, when positioning the cursor pointer and hiding when the pointer is moved out of the cursor.
The buttons have to have a simple event.

```
<div class="button-wrapper">
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any script that you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some jQuery that shows the icons/imgs when the user hovers over the labels parent div.

https://jsfiddle.net/yb4cdnzj/

**HTML**

```
<div class="lblClass">
  <label class="withBtns">Label 1</label>
  <div class="buttons">
    <img class="btn1" src="#">
    <img class="btn2" src="#">
    <img class="btn3" src="#">
  </div>
  <input type="text">

  <label>Label 2</label>
  <input type="text">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.lblClass {
  width: 50%;
  display: block;
}
label {
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}
.withBtns {
  float: left;
}
.buttons {
  display: none;
}
.buttons img {
  float: right;
  display: hidden;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".lblClass").hover(function() {
  $(".buttons").toggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

how about some css?

```
.form-horizontal .button-wrapper {
   display: none;
}
.form-horizontal:hover .button-wrapper {
   display: inline-block;
}
```